# How to display the names over named ranges in Excel?

Tags: excel

I accidentally dicovered that Excel 2010 can automatically display the names of named regions over them as some kind of an overlay layer:

[image: Excel 2010 displays named ranges over their respective region]

Based on my findings this occurs if two conditions are met:

- the view zoom level is not greater than 39%
- the name defines a range that is bigger than a single cell (but is still a single area)

Did you know this? Is this a bug or a feature?

How could I intentionally turn on this feature at possibly any zoom level?

Comment: I can't imagine that it is a bug. It seems like a rather nice feature if you want a birds-eye view of a complicated spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting result; I found so little on it that your post was on the first page of Bing's search results. It seems per here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/119051-dont-display-range-name-when-zooming.html that even though there is a command to make that name not appear when zoomed below 40%, there does not seem to be a command to change the threshold from 40% to something else.

You could perhaps use VBA code to move translucent word art shapes to align with the top left cell in any named range, but seems like a lot of work unless you have a specific payoff in mind.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/119051-dont-display-range-name-when-zooming.html) mentioned by @Grade was trying to remove the *named watermark* (attempting to coin a term here), but had only slight success with this macro:

```
Sub Hide_Names() 
Dim iName As Name 

For Each iName In ThisWorkbook.Names 
    iName.Visible = False 
Next iName 
End Sub
```

[This thread here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/8262-identify-named-ranges.html) (same forum) from 2002 was trying to answer your question, but go no answers... which means this feature was in Excel 2000 and is still poorly documented.

I just searched through all the Excel objects and Interop libraries for *name*, *zoom*, and *watermark* and found nothing resembling this feature.  Hopefully someone smarter can shed some light, but **I think your answer is simply "no."**